# figure out which button was pressed while differ between long-press and tap. swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

So I have listeners for a long and short-press on buttons, but I need to know what button was pressed.
Is it possible to find out what button was pressed in the tap and long function, or will I need to do two functions for each button?

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(long))
longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
smallOption.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
mediumOption.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
largeOption.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
smallOption.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
mediumOption.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
largeOption.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)

@objc func tap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("short-press")
}
@objc func long(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("long-press")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue, in this case, is both gestures will be added *ONLY* for the `largeOption` button! To clarify, the gesture is added only for one component, which in your case, it should be added only for the latest one (which is `largeOption`):

```
smallOption.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) <-- skipped
mediumOption.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) <-- skipped
largeOption.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) <-- added
smallOption.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture) <-- skipped
mediumOption.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture) <-- skipped
largeOption.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture) <-- added
```

Logically speaking, this might be the answer to your question:

> Is it possible to find out what button was pressed in the tap and long function, or will I need to do two functions for each button?

you need to add two gestures for each button because a particular gesture can only be added to one view.

However, you don't have to declare new action methods in addition to `@objc func tap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)` and `@objc func long(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)` existing ones. What you could do instead is to check the `sender`'s view. Example:

Let's assume that we manually added tow gestures for each button:

```
// gestures:
let smallOptionTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
let smallOptionLongGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(long))
smallOptionLongGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5

let mediumOptionTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
let mediumOptionLongGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(long))
mediumOptionLongGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5

let largeOptionTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
let largeOptionLongGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(long))
largeOptionLongGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5

// adding them:
smallOption.addGestureRecognizer(smallOptionTapGesture)
mediumOption.addGestureRecognizer(mediumOptionTapGesture)
largeOption.addGestureRecognizer(largeOptionTapGesture)

smallOption.addGestureRecognizer(smallOptionLongGesture)
mediumOption.addGestureRecognizer(mediumOptionLongGesture)
largeOption.addGestureRecognizer(largeOptionLongGesture)
```

Therefore, what you could do is:

```
@objc func tap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // an example of how you could check the button
    if sender.view == smallOption {
        print("small short-press")
    } else if sender.view == mediumOption {
        print("medium short-press")
    } else if sender.view == largeOption {
        print("large short-press")
    }
}
@objc func long(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // you could apply the same above approach here
}
```

The other option is to create action methods for each button separately.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two functions for the same gesture for each button. Change the method definition to accept `UIButton` (in your case) instead of `UIGestureRecognizer`. Afterwards, check the sender by verifying the tag or the type directly...

```
@objc func tap(_ sender: UIButton){
  switch sender {
  case button1: // or by tags of buttons
  case button2:
  ...
  default: break
}
```